# How to convert .bin video file to MP4 or AVI?

Tags: macos, video, video-conversion

I have a video file that has a `.bin` extension. I downloaded it off the web.

The website where I viewed it had a nice plugin viewer. But I want to keep this video in an easily accessible format on my disk. I'm a Mac OSX user (El-Capitan). So I would like to convert it to an `.avi` or `.mp4` with a free tool.

How can I do it? I tried using the [Mac Unarchiver](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12) but it said it couldn't open files of that type.

Comment: Write `file myfile.bin` from a shell to know if it is yet in a format _understandable_ then eventually rename it (do not convert kif it is not needed). Try to use vlc on it. If it is possible to play it do not convert again. With each conversion you have the risk to decrease the quality.

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide a download for this specific `.bin` file, I could check out its contents for you.

---

Usually, `.bin` files are ISO images. You could try some things:

- if the file comes with a `.cue` file, open that with Unarchiver instead.
- rename it into an `.iso` and try opening it again with Unarchiver. Rarely works though.
- download [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) and drag the file onto the window. VLC can play a wide range of formats including DVDs, so if your file is properly formatted, you can most certainly play it with VLC.
- download [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/downloads) and open the `.bin` or `.cue` with it.

---

If you're able to play the file with VLC but unable to open it with any archiving tool, your best bet might be to convert it to another format using VLC. This will get the video to another format, although it'd be a lossy conversion (you'd have a lower quality output).

Answer (score 1):

The online service https://www.files-conversion.com/ worked for me several times.

As an alternative you may use VLC player as mentioned on https://www.vlchelp.com/convert-video-format/ .

- launch VLC and click on File > Convert/Stream
  Open
- open your file, select the desired output format and start converting